# adding dependencies to fountainjs project

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator

I'm trying out the fountain-webapp yeoman generator for a simple project.  I've chosen:

```
? Which JavaScript framework do you want? Angular 1
? Which module management do you want? None with Bower and script injection
? Which JS preprocessor do you want? ES2015 today with Babel
? Which CSS preprocessor do you want? CSS
? Do you want a sample app? Just a Hello World
? Would you like a router? None
```

I can't seem to figure out however how to add additional dependencies like bootstrap, ui-bootstrap, etc.

I've tried installing bootstrap via npm/yarn and bower.  In the latter case I see a wiredep configuration:

```
exports.wiredep = {
  exclude: [/\/bootstrap\.js$/],
  directory: 'bower_components'
};
```

which explains the failure of the javascript injection but not the css. I also don't know what side effects removing that exclude will have.

Installing into node_modules, isn't being picked up by the injection either and trying to manually include the css, e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

the parent directory reference is being stripped off.

Can someone please advise me?

Thanks!

--john

Comment: You can add them however you normally would ... `npm install` or `yarn add`, download the source, etc.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to work for me.  I've updated the original question with a little more detail

Answer (score -1):

ciao, can you explain a little about how you download dependencies using bower? Like ui-bootstrap, the download command should be 'bower install angular-bootstrap --save'. Because when you want to automatically inject dependencies into your project, in the bower.json, it needs to add the plungin name in "dependencies" field. Or you can add dependencies' name with version, like '"angular-bootstrap": "^2.5.0"' manually in bower.json, then "bower update". Hope it helps you.